# How to use a map in hibernate when the key for the map is a user defined class

Tags: hibernate

I was trying to map different java collections using hibernate. I learnt about how to map a hashMap using the tag `<map/>` tag.
I learnt how to map the following:

1. `HashMap<String, String>`
2. `HashMap<String, UserDefinedClass>`

However i have a question.

How can I use map tag when i have to map a hashmap of this type `HashMap<UserdefinedClass, UserDefinedClass>`

essentially when the key to the map is not a java data type but a user defined class, how do i map it in hibernate.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For using user defined class as a key in HashMap you need to understand below points .

1. Hashing algorithm.
2. Purpose of hashCode() and equals() method.

Please read below for details working of HashMap.

[Working of HashMap](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/02/how-hashmap-works-in-java.html)

Comment: However the issue is still not clear to me. In case i ensure my hash map key is immutable, how do i map it to a table using hibernate.